# Setting a mysql column value to be the name of a php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table named `global_variables` with three columns `id`, `name`, `value`. I'd like to loop through all rows and make the `name` column the name of the variable and the value column its value. Sample data
**row 1**

```
`id`='1'
`name`='age'
`value`='35'
```

**row 2**

```
`id`='2'
`name`='gender'
`value`='Male'
```

Here is my code

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT `name`, `value` FROM `global_variables`");
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $$row['variable_name'] = $row['variable_value'];
}
echo $age; //This should display 35
echo $gender; //This should display Male
```

The problem is in the while loop at ***$$row['variable_name']***. How do implement naming a variable using the `name` column and assigning its value as the `value` column?

Comment: Use `${$row['variable_name']}`

Comment: Using variable variables is generally a bad idea. Consider using an array instead.

Comment: 'variable_name' and 'variable_value' are not defined/part of the SELECT

Comment: Thanks guys the problem has been solved. I'll consider your advice